# How does the std::piecewise_construct syntax work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a bit confused regarding `std::piecewise_construct` when used with `std::map`. Example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

// uses pair's piecewise constructor
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple("c"),
          std::forward_as_tuple(10, 'c'));
```

I'm not sure how `emplace()` knows how to handle this type of construction differently when `piecewise_construct` is used. Shouldn't it be: `std::piecewise_construct(std::forward_as_tuple("c"), std::forward_as_tuple(10, 'c'))`? How does it work with just commas, I don't see an overloaded comma operator or a special overload of `emplace` to handle piecewise and then variable args (as shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)).

Comment: `std::pair` has a matching constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair

Comment: For posterity: the name of this technique is tag dispatching: http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::map::emplace` directly calls the constructor with the arguments passed to `emplace` (forwarding them) of the type `std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type` (which is the typedef to `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`).

[`std::pair` has the constructor taking `std::piecewise_construct_t` (the type of the `std::piecewise_construct`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

Answer (score 5):

`map::emplace` simply forwards its arguments to the constructor of `pair<const K, V>`.  Pair has a constructor overload which takes `piecewise_construct` as the first argument.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair constructor #6